# I have the following code throwing and error.

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# This program records the names of 12 students in a list
# named students.
NUM_STUDENTS = 12

def main():
    # Create a list to hold the names of students.
    students = [0] * NUM_STUDENTS

    # Create a variable to hold an index
    index = 0

    print('Enter the names of 12 students.')

    # Add student names to the list.
    while index < NUM_STUDENTS:
        # Get the name of a student from the user.
        students[index] = input('Enter the name of a student: ')
        index += 1

        # Append a name to the student list.
        students.append(students)
```

Error when sorting? How do I fix this? line 24, in main
students.sort() TypeError: unorderable types: list() < str()

```
    # Sort the list of name alphabetically.
    students.sort()
    print('Alphabetically sorted list of names:', students)

    # Reverse the list of names
    students.reverse()
    print('Reverse sorted list of name:', students)
```

Comment: you dont need this line at end 
students.append(students)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line: `students.append(students)`. That adds the current `students` list to the end of itself, which makes no sense in this context. If you want to fix this, remove that line.